# Windows Form Icon not showing in Taskbar C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am adding an Icon to the Form i have created. When i run the program through VS2012 the icon shows up on the taskbar. But after publishing the project and installing it, the icon shows up in the Form border, but not in the taskbar. What am i doing wrong here?

I have tried resizing the icon.

Comment: And what is being shown on the task bar of the production evnironemnt? Is it the default icon of the `WinForms` applications?

Comment: eMi Solved my problem. Thanks for the help though! :) And yes it was the default blank window icon

Comment: So please accept the eMi's answer. This way everyone knows that you found the solution to your problem. This helps other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you go to the project's properties and set an icon in the Application tab (this should of course be the same icon used for the main window to avoid any confusion)?

Answer (score 8):

Did you go to form's properties and check line :Show icon = "True"?

Answer (score 3):

A dialog/form icon does not appear on taskbar until it receives proper keyboard focus. I am not quite sure what is the "proper" focus, but neither those who made windows were.This problem usaualy comes with missing of the first form activate event(oh yea it happends on regular basis). This may happen when you hide all the forms (in windows application) and then show the next form.
So this does not work:

```
newForm.Show () ;
currentForm.Hide () ; //The newForm does not have the proper focus yet

// actualy in this moment (I think) your application loose focus beacuse there is no application window.
```

This may do the trick:

```
newForm.Shown += newForm_Shown ;
newForm.Show () ;
void newForm_Shown ( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    currentForm.Hide () ;
}
```

Whenever you can, you should show the next form before you hide previous form, and then hide the current form during shown/activate event of the new form.
Additional workournd that I know is to do some delayed form activation. You could try something like BeginInvoke on some form activation method, but this is generaly bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Properties->Application->Icon and manifest

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a fix for a similar issue.

Every time I ran my program (in **debug** or **release** mode) from Visual Studio 2022, the taskbar displayed the standard generic icon.

[image]

But when I looked at the program using Windows Explorer, the executable was getting built with the correct icon.

[image]

##### My Fix

- I right clicked the executable in windows explorer, and selected "**Pin To Taskbar**".
- I then ran the program again from VS 2022, and the taskbar displayed the correct ICON.
- After running it, I **unpinned** it from the taskbar.

[image]

After that, the correct icon appeared when running it from VS 2022.

**FYI:** I had to perform this step for the executable in **release** and **debug** folders.

##### My Setup:

- **OS:** Windows 11 Pro
- **IDE:** Visual Studio 2022
- **Project:** C# Windows Forms App
- An ICO file set in Project-Properties->Application->[Win32 Resource]->Icon
- A PNG file 128x128 resolution set in Project-Properties->Package->General->Icon
- [image]

Answer (score 0):

What was happening in my case was that the taskbar icon was the form icon rather than the application icon, so you should check your form icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem , when i set `TopMost = false` the app appears in the taskbar.

Answer (score -1):

The Form and application icons were set in my project to an icon, but form "Show Icon" was hidden, and taskbar Icon was the blank rectangle.

Showing Icon on form both showed it on the form, AND updated the icon in the taskbar.