# Wrong icon in taskbar

Tags: c#, icons, taskbar, system-tray

Both Form1 and my desktop show the correct icon but the taskbar displays an icon I'm attempting to remove and replace with the proper one.  The taskbar icon being shown is the original one first used when I started coding.

The taskbar icon I'm talking about is toward the left ... not the system tray near the time display on the right.

Can anyone help me make this icon switch?  I don't know where else to look.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704370/windows-form-icon-not-showing-in-taskbar-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the project properties? And the project resources in the "Project properties" window?

To get there: Right-click the project in Visual Studio and select "Properties".