# .NET Windows Form not showing in taskbar

Tags: c#, themes, taskbar

My program does not appear in the taskbar when I run it. I should mention I use custom theme class called iTalk and I use it's Theme Container. It must be some sort of bug because when for example Message Box pops out and I press OK button then program shows in taskbar. Btw ShowIcon and ShowInTaskbar are both true. Any suggestion on how to fix it? (I don't just mean the icon image but the whole indication of a program running in taskbar is missing what I mean is after I minimize the application there is no way to resume it, I have to kill it in the task manager)

// The temporary solution I found is to open new form and instantly close it, but I really don't like it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Form Icon not showing in Taskbar C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704370/windows-form-icon-not-showing-in-taskbar-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Any situations like this clean project and build again. Then right TaskBar=true again. Hope it helps

Comment: that did not help